# Evaluate integral containing Erfc, Exp and Log

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to find the solution to the integral below. It runs in Mathematica but does not produce any output.
Every other part of the code works fine except the integral involving Exp, Erfc and Log functions.

How can this integral be evaluated symbolically or numerically? This is my complete code

```
Subscript[SNR, dB] = Range[10, 50, 5]
SNR = 10^(Subscript[SNR, dB]/10)
Subscript[a, 1] = 0.8
Subscript[a, 2] = 0.2
Subscript[d, sd] = 400
Subscript[d, sr] = 100
Subscript[d, rd] = 3*Subscript[d, sr]
p = 0.01
f = 30
Subscript[b, 0] = 9.4/10^3
Subscript[b, 1] = 4.2/10^7
k = 0.7
Subscript[σ, sr] = 
 Subscript[σ, rd] = Subscript[σ, sd] = 0.6
Subscript[μ, sr] = 
 Subscript[μ, rd] = Subscript[μ, sd] = 0.4
α = Subscript[b, 0] + Subscript[b, 1]*f^k
Subscript[A, sd] = Exp[(-α)*Subscript[d, sd]]
Subscript[A, sr] = Exp[(-α)*Subscript[d, sr]]
Subscript[A, rd] = Exp[(-α)*Subscript[d, rd]]; 
Subscript[num, 1] = 
 Exp[4*Subscript[μ, sd] + 2*Log[SNR*Subscript[A, sd]^2] + 
    8*Subscript[σ, sd]^2] + 
  Exp[4*Subscript[μ, rd] + 2*Log[SNR*Subscript[A, rd]^2] + 
    8*Subscript[σ, rd]^2]
Subscript[num, 2] = 
 Exp[4*Subscript[μ, sd] + 2*Log[SNR*Subscript[A, sd]^2] + 
    4*Subscript[σ, sd]^2] + 
  Exp[4*Subscript[μ, rd] + 2*Log[SNR*Subscript[A, rd]^2] + 
    4*Subscript[σ, rd]^2]
Subscript[dem, 1] = 
 Exp[4*Subscript[μ, sd] + 2*Log[SNR*Subscript[A, sd]^2] + 
    4*Subscript[σ, sd]^2] + 
  Exp[4*Subscript[μ, rd] + 2*Log[SNR*Subscript[A, rd]^2] + 
    4*Subscript[σ, rd]^2]
Subscript[dem, 2] = 
 Exp[(2*Subscript[μ, sd] + Log[SNR*Subscript[A, sd]^2] + 
     2*Subscript[σ, sd]^2) + (2*Subscript[μ, rd] + 
     Log[SNR*Subscript[A, rd]^2] + 2*Subscript[σ, rd]^2)]
Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, c]] = (1/4)*
  Log[(Subscript[num, 1] - Subscript[num, 2])/(Subscript[dem, 1] + 
       2*Subscript[dem, 2]) + 1]
Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]] = 
 Sqrt[Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, c]]]
Subscript[epart, 1] = 
 Exp[2*Subscript[μ, sd] + Log[SNR*Subscript[A, sd]^2] + 
    2*Subscript[σ, sd]^2] + 
  Exp[2*Subscript[μ, rd] + Log[SNR*Subscript[A, rd]^2] + 
    2*Subscript[σ, rd]^2]
Subscript[μ, 
  Subscript[W, 
   sd + rd]] = (1/2)*(Log[Subscript[epart, 1]] - 
    2*Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]]^2)
Subscript[Λ, sr] = Log[SNR*Subscript[A, sr]^2]
Subscript[c, cap] = ((1 - p)/Sqrt[128*Pi])*
  Integrate[(1/u)*
    Log2[1 + 
      u]*((1/Subscript[σ, sr])*
       Erfc[(Log[u] - 2*Subscript[μ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]])/
         Sqrt[8*Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]]^2]]*

       Exp[-((Log[u] - 2*Subscript[μ, sr] + 
              Subscript[Λ, sr])^2/(8*
             Subscript[σ, sr]^2))] + (1/
         Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]])*
       Erfc[(Log[u] - 2*Subscript[μ, sr] + 
           Subscript[Λ, sr])/(Sqrt[8]*
           Subscript[σ, sr])]*

       Exp[-((Log[u] - 
              2*Subscript[μ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]])^2/(8*
             Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]]^2))]), {u, 0, 
    Infinity}]
```

Comment: It is very likely that this integral has no closed-form solution. You should try `NIntegrate` for numerical intergration. But for making this work, you will have to specify numeric values for all symbols (except `u` of course).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I have already tried using NIntegrate but mathematica doesnot produce any output.

Comment: Because there must be undefined symbols left.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The undefined symbols have been defined in my actual code.

Comment: In your actual code the only defined symbol is `Subscript[c, cap]` which isn't used anywhere. By the way the use of `Subscript[]` is sometimes dangerous...

Comment: Hi Silvreback and welcome!  You should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://goo.gl/sa5ME8) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](https://goo.gl/c5z1S2) to the oprator `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://goo.gl/yj1VuQ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integrand is a list, since the first two lines are lists.

Map the NIntegrate to that list.

```
integrand = (1/u)*
  Log2[1 + 
 u]*((1/Subscript[σ, sr])*
  Erfc[(Log[u] - 2*Subscript[μ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]])/
    Sqrt[8*Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]]^2]]*
  Exp[-((Log[u] - 2*Subscript[μ, sr] + 
         Subscript[Λ, sr])^2/(8*
        Subscript[σ, sr]^2))] + (1/
    Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]])*
  Erfc[(Log[u] - 2*Subscript[μ, sr] + 
      Subscript[Λ, sr])/(Sqrt[8]*
      Subscript[σ, sr])]*
  Exp[-((Log[u] - 2*Subscript[μ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]])^2/(8*
        Subscript[σ, Subscript[W, sd + rd]]^2))]);

Subscript[c, cap] = 
((1 - p)/Sqrt[128*Pi])*NIntegrate[#, {u, 0, Infinity}] & /@ integrand

(*   {0.102147, 0.171806, 0.135395, 0.0586042, 0.0203224, 0.00664875, \
      0.00212865, 0.00067595, 0.000214043}   *)
```